# how to drag a jpanel with graphics across the jframe

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel

I have the following code for a constructor:

```
public Building(Graphics g, int xb, int yb, int wb, int lb,boolean chklocb, Point nwlocb) {
        x=xb;
        y=yb;
        w=wb;
        l=lb;
        chkloc=chklocb;
        nwloc=nwlocb;
        if(chkloc){
            x = (int)nwloc.getX();
            y = (int)nwloc.getY();
            //System.out.print(i);
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("mhffffff");
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x,y,w,l);
        g.fillRect(x,y,w,l);
    }
```

And I have tried using setLocation() to move it. 
This only made it disappear.
This is how I tried to move it:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        //pset=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        //panel.setVisible(false);
        if(panel.contains(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation())){
            contains=true;
        }
        if(contains){
            //panel=new Building(getGraphics(),(int)ptrck.x,(int)ptrck.y,100,100,contains,pset);
            //panel.Nwloc(pset);
            // remove(panel);
            // constraints.gridx=(int)pset.getX();
            // constraints.gridy=(int)pset.getY();
            // add(panel);
            e.translatePoint(e.getComponent().getLocation().x-x, e.getComponent().getLocation().y-y);
            panel.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());

            z.prnt("testcontain");
        }
    }
```

How can I drag it?

Comment: Check out the [Component Mover](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a reusable class that allows you to drag any component.

Comment: I tried that and I got the same result, it just disappears.

Comment: Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.